Is it possible not to consume an update with python-telegram-bot?
I am working on a small telegram bot using python-telegram-bot package.
While debugging I have to send the same test message to the bot again and again.
Even if I stop the program in debug pause mode (in messages handler code), it does something on closing consuming the update I am currently working on.
I can see it in my browser for as long as I do not stop the process in my IDE (Pycharm Community).
Then it goes away.
Any chance I can avoid sending the same test message a million times?
Maybe I'm missing something, there must be a way to debug more gracefully.
Any help would be appreciated!

I don't understand your problem.

Apparently all I had to do was turning on Emulate terminal in output console in my Pycharm run configuration
Strangely it only worked after the third try but now it works like expected: the process shuts down immediately without any exit actions and the update is not consumed
